# Compute this (probably really easy) double integral (domain is only drawn).

Tags: integration

For some reason it doesn't let me attach the image in this post, probably it's too big, so i link it from an external site.( [Here](http://oi65.tinypic.com/sv54jp.jpg) ).

I have to integrate the function $\frac{1}{8}(x+2)(y+1)$ over the $\mathcal{D}$ domain. The attempt I made is to decompose the domain in two parts, say $\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{D}_1 \cup \mathcal{D}_2$ where $\mathcal{D}_1$ is the rectangle delimited by $x = 0, x = -1, y = 1, y = -1$. and $\mathcal{D}_2$ is the semicircle on the right. With this decomposition I got that

$\iint_\limits{\mathcal{D}}\frac{1}{8}(x+2)(y+1)dxdy = \iint_\limits{\mathcal{D}_1}\frac{1}{8}(x+2)(y+1)dxdy + \iint_\limits{\mathcal{D}_2}\frac{1}{8}(x+2)(y+1)dxdy$

Doing the first integral I had no problem I think, and I got as result $\iint_\limits{\mathcal{D}_1}\frac{1}{8}(x+2)(y+1)dxdy = \frac{3}{8}$.

By the other side, for computing the integral over the semicircle I decided to swap to  polar coordinates and had some difficulty deciding which where $\rho$ and $\theta$ 's ranges. Just basing myself on my eye, I established that $\rho$ goes from $0$ to $1$  (the circle of radius $1$), and $\theta$ goes from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, cause it looks like a "rotated" semicircle.

With this swap I got as result that $\iint_\limits{\mathcal{D}_2}\frac{1}{8}(x+2)(y+1)dxdy = \frac{2 + 3\pi}{24}$ so summing up the two previous I get that
$\iint_\limits{\mathcal{D}}\frac{1}{8}(x+2)(y+1)dxdy = \frac{1}{24}(11 + 3\pi)$.

Is this correct? (I'm asking cause I'm not sure and no solution is reported on my source).

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Comment: I did it a different way, and I got the same answer as you. Note that $\iint_\limits{\mathcal{D}}\frac{1}{8}(x+2)\;y\;dxdy$ is zero, by symmetry in $y$; so you only need to evaulate $\iint_\limits{\mathcal{D}}\frac{1}{8}(x+2)dxdy$.